# Truly transparent gradient possible in Fireworks CS5?

Tags: transparency, gradient, fireworks

Does anyone know if it's possible to have a gradient created using Fireworks to be really transparent at the bottom?
I'm trying to create a gradient which is truly transparent at the bottom, so it can be placed on top of another image. As far as I'm aware, even though the opacity of the bottom is 0, I still have to select a color for the bottom. This makes the top color blend into it (like below it's blending into white). So whenever the image is placed over a dark image the bottom is transparent but still white.

[image]

Hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I usually achieve this effect by setting both color endpoints of the gradient to the same color, then adjusting the opacity endpoint to 0% (or whatever you want).

[image: FW gradient panel]

Here's the result: This is `#666/100% to #666/0%` on the left, `#666/100% to white/0%` on the right.

[image: side by side gradient comparison]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem you should try working with auto vector masks
Command>Creative>Auto Vector Mask

Great little tutorial here
http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=b5f64

Answer (score 0):

How are you defining "really transparent"?

You must choose a linear gradient, then a colour at each end of the gradient, and then make one end opacity 0%. It doesn't matter if it is a colour or not, you make it invisible anyway.

If you are comparing it to something like Photoshop or Illustrator, yes it's annoying that Adobe cannot be consistent with how each application handles opacity, but in Fireworks, it's still the same effect, just a different method of doing it.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine but it's possible to see the 'invisible' colour. For example, the image in my question doesn't look right if placed on a dark image. You can still see the white in the bottom.

Comment: Maybe you are not adjusting the opacity of the colour? If you choose a linear gradient, when you choose the bottom colour, you set it to any colour, but the marker at the top you must adjust to opacity 0%. Then it becomes transparent.